# How can I turn off VPN?

Tags: ios, vpn

I'm working on a friend's iPhone and every time I turn VPN off, it turns right back on.

Have you ever seen this before?

Any suggestions for what I could do to keep it turned off?

Comment: It is possible that your friend has VPN on demand in use, in which case you may not be able to turn it off. In order to answer your question, can you check on what type of VPN your friend is using?

Comment: @Scot it's possible. Where do I check that?

Comment: There may be a configuration profile - go to Settings->General->Profiles. Which iOS version?

Comment: @Scot that did it! Could you add it as an answer so I can vote it up and help anyone else who has this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is another step in here...

iOS > Settings > General > VPN > ~YourVPN_Profile (Click the 'i' icon) > Connect On Demand (turn toggle switch to 'off') = sorted!

NB. Use the VPN option under Settings > General... Not the 'VPN' switch under Settings!

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm doing. The problem is that every time I turn it off it turns right back on.

Comment: This worked for me. You have to be sure to go to "General" -> "VPN", and not just go to the VPN on the first "Settings" screen (this is on iOS 12.3.1)